# apex:detail title bug?

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, dynamic-visualforce

I've looked everywhere and it seems like  I'm the only one with the problem.

I've created a visualforce page and use apex: detail to reference my object. Everything shows up fine but I don't want the title portion and title="false" just doesn't do what it's documented to do. Is there a workaround for this?

Here's my vf page -

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Position__c">
   <apex:detail title="false" subject="{!Position__c.Company__c}" relatedList="false"/> 
</apex:page>
```

[image]

That's the rendered page. As you can see the title is still present. 
My object is Position that has a master-detail relationship to Company.

**UPDATE***

Seems like this attribute is only handled when the VisualForce page is a tab and not when it's a section of the layout on an object (which is really counter-intuitive since the demo shows the latter).

Comment: did you try with title = "true" and see if the same gets rendered?I feel that the title is hidden but the further headers you see are the ones you mistake as title here

Comment: I thought about that as well and tried it and it renders the same.

Comment: can you try with sidebar= false and see if it loads differently if it does there is some sidebar JS that's disabling your title that can be investigated later

Comment: apex:detail doesn't support sidebar so vf page is not letting me compile.

Comment: try sidebar= "false" it does let you disable sidebar, the earlier comment did not have "" on the false tag.

Comment: yeah added those and getting  Error: Unsupported attribute sidebar in <apex:detail> at line 2 column 87

Comment: add the sidebar="false" to the <apex:page> not the <apex:detail>

Comment: Oh i see. I tried that as well and it didn't work. Same thing rendered.

Comment: @Oakage , did you find any way to remove the "Company Detail" Text in your example? I am also looking into this and have not found a way to do this. I am using the visual force page in my standard Page Layout, no tabs or anything like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The title bar is this section of the page where the record type and record name are displayed:

[image: title bar]

---

### `title="true"`

Using a single `apex:detail` component with `title = "true"` gives this output:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account"> 
    <apex:detail subject="{!account.Id}" relatedList="false" title="true"/>
</apex:page>
```

[image: title=true]

---

### `title="false"`

Using a single `apex:detail` component with `title = "false"` gives this output:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account"> 
    <apex:detail subject="{!account.Id}" relatedList="false" title="false"/>
</apex:page>
```

[image: title=false]

---

### Two `apex:detail` components

Where things get interesting is when you add two `apex:detail` components to the same page, one with `title="true"` and one with `title="false`, in that case you get the title bar at the top of the page, rather than above the details detail that you specified `title="true"` on.

[image: two apex:detail]

Comment: I see. This is a visual force page tab. I had it as a visualforce element in an objects layout

Answer (score 2):

As the VF document said `Title: A Boolean value that specifies whether the title bar is included in the rendered component.`

Title bar is highlight in my screenshot, not the below one.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if that is correct. Setting title to true or false does not render this portion as mentioned in my earlier comments. Salesforce's visualforce detail example "<apex:page standardController="Account">
   <apex:detail subject="{!account.ownerId}" relatedList="false" title="false"/> 
</apex:page>" renders the same for both true and false.

Comment: as shown from below this seems to be a visualforce page tab only implementation